# Will Divorced Wifes go to heaven if they die before Husband passes away?

Tags: belief, practice, superstitions

Usually, wives do Tulasi pooja and to be Muthaidhe and they pray for it to attain heaven by dying before their Husbands.

These practices now drastically come down but still, traditional people follow. Bheemana Amavaasye is so auspicious for every Husband.

My ask is what happens to those who are not in a relationship together or divorced. And those Wives are still doing Tulasi Pooja, will they go to Heaven as per the husband and wife relationship?

Comment: Women are not allowed to leave husband even if he is wicked, dumb and useless.  So,  what puja is of any use?

Comment: ...and why would you believe that the husband goes first? What is the jiva of the wife supposed to do meanwhile? To think that the jiva of the wife has to wait for the husband is contrary to scripture.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - Because of Age differences